# Count User Blogs Prior to Worpdress Login Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to build the following functionality for a Wordpress Multisite install:

- On login execution the number of blogs that a user is a member of (less the primary Wordpress site) is counted, and then -
- If a user is a member of more than one site they are directed to a gateway page where they can choose the site they would like to visit.
- If a user is member of only one site then they are redirected straight to that site.

I've written the following code which works to a degree. When a user logs in they are currently directed to their primary blog, if they log in again (even though they are already logged in) they are redirected to the gateway, suggesting that the count of the number of blogs is not working on initial login. Has anyone any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
/*Redirect After Login on front end*/
function primary_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) 
{
    if ($user->ID != 0) 
    {
        $user_info = get_current_user_id();
        //Get number of blogs from user 
        //$blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_info );
        // if($blogs > 1) {

        $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_info );
        $result = count($user_blogs);

        if ($result > 1){
            $primary_url = 'https://xxxyyyzzz.com/gateway-page/';
            if ($primary_url) {
                wp_redirect($primary_url);
                die();
            }
        } else {
            $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
            if ($user_info->primary_blog) {
                $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) . 'home/';
                if ($primary_url) {
                    wp_redirect($primary_url);
                    die();
                }
            }
        }

        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter('login_redirect','primary_login_redirect', 100, 3);
```

Comment: `if (($result - "1") > "1") {` <-- This is your problem. If the user has 2 blogs this will not pass. Also your mixing up integers with strings, stick to one type. I think maybe you intended to use `if($result > 1){` ?

Comment: Thanks for the input, you're right about the integers but I'm afraid that still didn't work, again the blogs dont seem to be counted on login, I've updated the code to reflect your changes

Comment: In that case you need to start debugging. After the $user_blogs variable declaration do `print_r($user_blogs);die();`. Then login and see if you get your expected output.

Comment: the result is: Array ( ) but this is my question, $user_info = get_current_user_id(); does not seem to work when logging in for the first time but does work when the user is already logged in. Do you know how can i get the user id effectively during the log in process to query the number of blogs that a user is a member of?

Comment: What is the `$user` parameter being passed to the method? Does this not have access to the user id? Something like `$user->ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `get_current_user_id()` doesn't return a result at this stage of the login process.

Instead of using the `get_current_user_id()` method, try accessing the id from the `$user` parameter being passed to the method.

```
if ($user->ID != 0) 
{
    $userBlogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user->ID );
    $numBlogs = count($userBlogs);
}
```

You could refactor your code to make it a lot more readable.

```
function primary_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) 
{
    if ($user->ID != 0) 
    {
        $userBlogs = get_blogs_of_user($user->ID);
        $numBlogs = count($userBlogs);

        if ($numBlogs > 1) {
            wp_redirect('https://xxxyyyzzz.com/gateway-page/');
            die();
        } 

        if ($user->primary_blog) {
            $url = get_blogaddress_by_id($user->primary_blog) . 'home/';
            wp_redirect($url);
            die();
        }

        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works a treat, thanks so much, also for the refactoring, certainly makes things cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
function primary_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) 
{
    if ($user->ID != 0) 
    {
        $user_info = get_current_user_id();
        //Get number of blogs from user 
        //$blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_info );
        // if($blogs > 1) {

        //$user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_info );
        $result = count( get_posts( array( "post_type" => "post", "posts_per_page" => -1, "author" => $user_info )) );

        if ($result > 1){
            $primary_url = 'https://xxxyyyzzz.com/gateway-page/';
            if ($primary_url) {
                wp_redirect($primary_url);
                die();
            }
        } else {
            $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
            if ($user_info->primary_blog) {
                $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) . 'home/';
                if ($primary_url) {
                    wp_redirect($primary_url);
                    die();
                }
            }
        }

        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter('login_redirect','primary_login_redirect', 100, 3);
?>
```

As far as I checked
`echo json_encode(get_blogs_of_user( 1 )); // 1 is admin`

it only returned

```
{"1":{"userblog_id":1,"blogname":"WOO","domain":"","path":"","site_id":1,"siteurl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp","archived":0,"spam":0,"deleted":0}}
```

Which your code will always give `1`. So counting custom is better.

Good luck.